# ZK - how to show 1Million rows in a table / grid

Tags: java, database, client, zk

So far I've seen examples that use the following logic:

1. Create a table / grid object
2. Set its data source (Collection such as array list/ set)
3. The table shows the entries on the client side!

Problem is, we have millions of rows to display, (on a side note I tried to load the container with all the entries, it took tons of time, and the client side performance were lacking)

So that raises the question:

> How do you show huge amount of data on the zk tables \ grids? Wishful
>   thinking points me to think that instead of an array list data source
>   i could set a DB connection or something instead, and that will manage
>   the results on demand with paging.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why loading data when you are not displaying all the rows at a time.

Retieve only those data that should be displayed and load the other data on demand not while the page is initially loading.

if you try to fetch 1 million rows and try to bind it to a control, it will hugely effect your application performance and increases the time for  your page to load.

So, my adivce should be fetch only those rows that needs to be displayed. if the request comes from the user for the next set of pages then load that data and bind.

you can make ajax calls to avoid every time entire page refershing

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

ZK give [BigListbox](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Biglistbox) to show huge record